# Access Button's LinearLayout through its OnClickListener

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I have a few `Buttons` in a `LinearLayout`. Both are dynamically created. Is there a way I can access the `LinearLayout` through the `Button`? I set the `LinearLayouts` `id's` to 0 or 1. So I only want the buttons to do something if they are in a `LinearLayout` equal to 1.

Code:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(view.getContext());
linearLayout.setId(1);
Button dynamicButtons = new Button(view.getContext());
...
...
...
linearLayout.addView(dynamicButtons, layoutParam);
```

So now I added the `Button` to the `LinearLayout`. Can I do something like this for the `Button's` `OnClickListener`:

```
dynamicButtons.setOnClickListener( 
    new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
        if (dynamicButton.getParentView().getId()==1){ //When I click the Button, I want to access the LinearLayout the Button is in
            //do something
        }

    }
});
```

Of course this line `dynamicButton.getParentView().getId()==1` is wrong. But how can I access that `Button's` `LinearLayout?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. All you need to do is cast to linear layout.

```
dynamicButtons.setOnClickListener( 
    new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
          LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) dynamicButtons.getParent();
          if (ll.getId()==1){ //When I click the Button, I want to access the LinearLayout the Button is in
          //do something
        }

    }
});
```